# why border is around child positioned relative

Tags: html, css

I want to know why the content of the absolutely positioned div is overflowing out of the border and how to set the height of the container to be sure that nothing will overflow. knowing  that the height of child are variable.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ff0000
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="card" class="container">
  <div class="absolute">
    <h1 style="margin-left : 200px">beaucoup de texte</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="relative">
    <h1>moins de texte</h1>
    hello and welcome
  </div>
</div>
```

another way to explain that in this jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/jjjepmwm/5/

Comment: There is a border around .container -- which is the biggest div. http://codepen.io/sol_b/pen/jyqapw

Comment: My question is why it is not containing div positioned absolute, thanks

Comment: the *absolutely positioned* `absolute` means it is taken of the normal flow and you won't be able to grow the `container` as `absolute` grows... so the answer is that you **can't**

Comment: to add to kukkuz: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: ... so the solution is to not position the biggest div absolutely.

Comment: @kukkuz  is there any way to grows it using just css,

Comment: I think you've fundamentally misunderstood what absolute positioning is. Perhaps reframe your question as to what _you want to achieve_, because there _will_ be a solution to _that_. There isn't a solution to how to change the behaviour of absolute positioning using CSS.

Comment: OK I well edit the question, to be more clear

Comment: Maybe this question can be salvaged if you explain why the inner div must be positioned absolutely. Otherwise, you will only get low-quality answers (guesswork as to what you're trying to achieve).

Comment: it absolute because i have to deal with `jquery flip`  library and one of the child is the front of the card and the other is the back.

Comment: @MrLister check the link please to  know that I have reason and that they have just no response to the question

Answer (score 0):

The border is to your biggest div only. Problem with your code is you have created one absolute div which will not know the bounds of it's parent. you can hide content if it's overflowing though.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely-positioned elements are taken out of the layout. Parent div will not clear it's absolutely-positioned child div.

You need to set the height of the parent div so that the child div does not flow out of it.

```css
.container {
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 20px;
  height:150px;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  color: #ff0000
}
.relative {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="card" class="container">
  <div class="absolute">
    <h1 style="margin-left : 200px">beaucoup de texte</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="relative">
    <h1>moins de texte</h1>
    hello and welcome
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the height of my **absolutely ** div is dynamic, I want to make the height of the container relative to the  **absolutely **div

Comment: this is the only css solution to the `absolute`. There may be a javascript solution or  If you edit your question to tell what you are trying to achieve then there might be another way to achieve that than `absolute`

Comment: I can do it with JavaScript alone I want to do it using CSS

Answer (score 0):

use `position` the correct. `position: relative` sets a count start for embedded `position: absolute`

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;

  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: 20px;

  background-color: blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what shoud I do if the height of child is dynamic

Comment: @Deyd try other methods of positioning